# preventing CSRF in a website POST request

Tags: java, jsp, csrf, tomcat8, csrf-protection

I need to refact but not so much a webapp (jsp without tag libraries) for prevent CSRF attack. I can't use an algorithm like describe here, but i think nonce id is the best solution for me:  https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html#CSRF_Prevention_Filter_for_REST_APIs
Apply these arguments, is very expensive because i have to change all calling request (add a get for every Post and force client to do second call), so  i decide to add an input hidden text box in all my jsp using a static include import, and a java Filter for matching session Nonce ID and request nonce ID. Is it my solution a good practice and an alternative to rest algorithm?
Sorry for my bad english..

Thanks!

Roby

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is called a honeypot captcha, which offers some protection but it is not close to safety. If you use this approach, then I, as a user will be able to edit your html and easily hack your site. Also, I can watch from the requests what is being sent and write my own program which will send you requests. So no, this is not a good approach on its own, but it is not a bad thing if you use it accompanied with real protection.

Comment: What do you mean for Real protection? for example http secure (https/tls)?

Comment: @robyp7, that's actually an excellent question. By real protection I am referring to not believe the client-side that the data is correct and do all the critical security-related stuff on server-side. Off course, you need to make sure there is no SQL injection possibility, that you cope with DDOS attacks well and so on and so on and so on. There are literally tons of books in the topic and we just scratched the surface.